# How to cap camera lerping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to put a cap on when to stop the camera from following my character. The desired stop values are 0.3 and -0.3. I have tried using if statements to tell it to stop lerping when it reaches these values, however as soon as it hits one of the values the lerping stops forever.

```
this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, new Vector3(xPositionOfAllPlayers / player.Length, yPositionOfAllPlayers / player.Length, this.transform.position.z), 0.1f);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are [using `Lerp()` incorrectly](http://www.blueraja.com/blog/404/how-to-use-unity-3ds-linear-interpolation-vector3-lerp-correctly).

Second of all, to clamp the values of a Vector, you can use [`Mathf.Clamp()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

```
Vector3 cameraPosition = Vector3.Lerp(/*Put arguments here, see link above*/);

this.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(cameraPosition.x, -0.3, 0.3),
                            Mathf.Clamp(cameraPosition.y, -0.3, 0.3),
                            cameraPosition.z);
```